# Magento redirects to page not found for products for some times only

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.7, product

I am facing a strange issue. I donot know that any one faced it or not. When I click on the products in the listing page, sometimes it redirects to page not found page(404page) and some times it goes to the product view page. I have reindexing  all the items and cleared cache several times. But no luck. This is happening when I move from old server to new server.

Can anyone suggest me any ideas on this.. I am using magento 1.7.0.2.

Comment: is product accessible or not???

Comment: some times it is accessible and some times it is not(this means it redirect to page not found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous week  i have facing the same issue....
I have emptying  below  table----
all log tables

```
 log_customer
    log_quote
    log_summary
    log_summary_type
    log_url_info
    log_url
    log_visitor
    log_visitor_info
    log_visitor_online
report_viewed_product_index
```

it was working.

Comment: I think this too will help me. Till now my cache is disabled and I made it enabled. From then I am not facing any issues of page not found. Let me clear these tables too for making my site as perfect site. Thank you Amit...

Comment: "report_viewed_product_index" --  This table does the magic... Now everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Linux always check the ownership of your files. Maybe many of the files in your cache are under some user and others from other user. This could be the root cause of the issue.

Regards!